# force 'uget' to download from a particular link

Tags: downloads, download-manager, uget

I'm using `uget` on Ubuntu 13.10, but the problem is that it doesn't download from some links automatically.

For example, I want to download a file from http://d-h.st/ONi :

> *When I click the download button, the download starts in the browser itself... I cant find any way to force download it in `uget`.*

Is there any download manager which can download this file by simply clicking on the download button ? Just like "Orbit Downloader" or "Internet Download Manager" on Windows ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

My personal preference is [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/home/index?s=lng_en), which does work perfectly fine on your [link/file](http://d-h.st/ONi), as the screenshot shows.

> JDownloader is a free, open-source download management tool with a huge community of developers that makes downloading as easy and fast as it should be. Users can start, stop or pause downloads, set bandwith limitations, auto-extract archives and much more. It's an easy-to-extend framework that can save hours of your valuable time every day!

1. To install, use either Ubuntu Software-Center,
2. or follow this [link](http://jdownloader.org/download/index) on their homepage

> JDownloader requires Java Runtime Enviroment (jre/jdk) 1.5 or higher. If possible, you should use the latest Java version.

**How to automatically download added links**:

You have to mark and copy <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the url of the file you intend to download though, which will then copy it into JD.

From there it autostarts the download, if you checked the option `start downloads after adding` in Addons -> AddonManager -> Linkgrabber.

Comment: JDownloader requires Java to work so if someone can avoid that then they should. Especially since JDownloader has been flagged on sites like alternativeto.net - http://alternativeto.net/software/jdownloader/ (this is likely exclusive to the Windows version but if they will do it on Windows why trust them to not do it in Linux later)

Comment: I agree for the java part, (for which I could do without just fine)!! Anyway it is worth it for years now imo. For the information in your link I can only say: It may be the case with win-versions, but we use linux instead and for now JD is a great choice. What comes next is always the question, but when the time comes, we simply adapt to the circumstances putting your needs and wants in front of theirs, right!

Comment: I approach the situation in a idealistic but practical manner. If a company/project is willing to act in bad faith in Windows why should I give them any leeway for their app in Linux? If they are willing to have bad practices, then I am not willing to use their program. - if others are ok with that then fine but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: As it is right now, the malware, toolbar addons are only related to the windows version of JD, so why just bother with it for now in linux? People also use/used `whatsapp` (which came so cheap in comparison to sms services, because the whatsapp devs made a business out of it, by selling their users personal/senitive data to 3rd party data-collector/advertisers) and now since facebook took over, the media is all over it, (which doesnt hold some people back from still using it). We are talking about this moment, and the next, we (hopefully) simply adapt to the changes, as I was saying.

Comment: with JDownloader I don't trust people to do something in good faith when I already know they have done stuff in bad faith, regardless of platform. - With whatsapp sure they were quite shady but comparing WhatsApp to SMS is not a legitimate comparison because there are DOZENS of other options. eBuddy XMS is basically the same purpose of WhatsApp but isn't mobile only and actually has desktop clients and webapps. In fact, you could already use Facebook IM on Android via Xabber or on Linux via Pidgin. So many options to compare to WhatsApp and eBuddy for example is more feature and just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with the download manager you are using, it applies to the website creating the button without a link and instead creates the button with Javascript.

The solution is to use an extension that can catch the download from the link and send it to any download manager you want.

If you are a Firefox user than the solution is FlashGot...if you are a Chrome user then there really isn't a solution for that yet. (though the uGet team is working on it)

FlashGot - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/

Just install that, it will automatically detect that you are using uGet and it will give you the option to send that download directly to uGet when you click the button.

---

Also make sure you are using the latest version of uGet, the Software Center is out of date for 13.10. - http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu

PPA is a solution to install a new repo, in this case the official Upstream repo from uGet.

DEB files are similar to EXE files that Windows uses...just download the DEB file to your desktop, double click it and choose to install.